# How to calculate which Candidate has the most first preference (1) votes. Using Arrays?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to make a voting system where there is 5 candidates that voters have to rank in order of who they prefer most. Ranking 1 as their most favourite and 5 as their least. I have used numericupdown scrollers for the inputting of the data. I then need to calculate the candidate with the lowest score and if there is a draw the candidate with the most number 1's or if still a draw the most number of 2's etc. This is what I have so far and I am getting stuck on the calculating bit. I can identify the candidate with the lowest number but if there is a vote I need to look at which candidate had the most number of one votes and if still a draw who had the most number of two votes ect. I am coding this using Visual Basic. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Dim int As Integer
int = NumericUpDownC1V1.Value
int = NumericUpDownC1V2.Value
int = NumericUpDownC1V3.Value
int = NumericUpDownC1V4.Value
int = NumericUpDownC1V5.Value

Dim Candidate1Total As Integer
Dim Candidate2Total As Integer
Dim Candidate3Total As Integer
Dim Candidate4Total As Integer
Dim Candidate5Total As Integer

Try

    Candidate1Total = NumericUpDownC1V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC1V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC1V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC1V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC1V5.Value * 5)
    Candidate2Total = NumericUpDownC2V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC2V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC2V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC2V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC2V5.Value * 5)
    Candidate3Total = NumericUpDownC3V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC3V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC3V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC3V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC3V5.Value * 5)
    Candidate4Total = NumericUpDownC4V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC4V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC4V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC4V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC4V5.Value * 5)
    Candidate5Total = NumericUpDownC5V1.Value + (NumericUpDownC5V2.Value * 2) + (NumericUpDownC5V3.Value * 3) + (NumericUpDownC5V4.Value * 4) + (NumericUpDownC5V5.Value * 5)

    Label7.Text = Candidate1Total
    Label8.Text = Candidate2Total
    Label9.Text = Candidate3Total
    Label10.Text = Candidate4Total
    Label11.Text = Candidate5Total

Catch

End Try


If Candidate2Total < winner Then
    winner = Candidate2Total

End If
If Candidate3Total < winner Then
    winner = Candidate3Total

End If
If Candidate4Total < winner Then
    winner = Candidate4Total

End If
 If Candidate5Total < winner Then
    winner = Candidate5Total

End If
Label3.Text = winner
```

[image: UI]

Comment: Your candidate total formula appears to be wrong. If I chose all 1's for a candidate then the score I appear to get is `1 + 1 x 2 + 1 x 3 + 1 x 4 + 1 x 5`. Shouldn't I simply get `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`?

Comment: Its because there is a form with vote preferences across the top and candidate names down the side. there is numeric up and down arrows to pick your preferences. Therefore a candidate with a 1 vote, a 2 vote a 3 vote will have 3+2+1 as their score.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that what they pick with the `NumericUpDown` control? Doesn't the user choose the values? Or do the `NumericUpDown` only have `0` & `1`?

Comment: no you can put whatever number in. HOwever I need the program to calculate the winner once a submit button is pressed. So it will take the values of the numeric up and downs and multiply them by the preference to work out how many 1's, 2's, 3's ect they have to get a total score.

Comment: Multiplying them by the preference doesn't work out how many 1's, 2's, etc, you have.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your UI?

Comment: Really sorry but could you tell me how to add a screenshot. I have tried to paste it in comments but its not working. Sorry and thank you for your patience. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just edit your question and you can post the image.

Comment: Sorry it says I do not have enough reputation points to post images!!! AHHH

Comment: Please email it to me at "stackoverflow" at my username dot com and I'll edit your question.

Comment: I got your screenshot and posted the image. I don't understand how a user will work with that UI. Can you please explain how a user would use the screen? **And**, what will the values in the values in the controls look like when they are done?

Comment: A user would use the UI to enter the number of 1st preference, 2nd preference, 3rd preference, 4th preference and 5th preference votes each candidate had got from the voting ballots. When the user hits submit it calculate the total score for each candidate. Hope that makes sense. The scrolls just increment by 1 each time you press up.

Comment: It's still not making sense. Can you give me an example of what they might enter?

Comment: It's an application that will be used to determine the winner an election for new members of a School Council where each year group has to elect a candidate.
 Pupils must complete the ballot slip for their year group and rank the candidates in order of preference,with 1 indicating their favourite choice and 5 their least favourite.The head teacher has decided that candidates will be awarded points reflecting the value of their preference votes.
 For each candidate, the points from all ballot papers will be added together
 The candidate with the lowest total points will be declared the winner

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how the UI makes that happen. The UI doesn't seem to be designed right.

Comment: The person who uses that screen would be the person with all the ballot papers. They would go through them and use the scrollers to enter the number of 1 votes, 2 votes, 3 votes, 4 votes and 5 votes each candidate had.

Comment: Is the screen for entering a single voter's ballot paper? So that most of the up-downs remain zero and you select up only once (getting a "1") to indicate which row and column matches the ballot paper?

Comment: That would mean, based on your code, that each `NumericUpDownC{x}V{y}.Value` can only be either `0` or `1`?

Comment: Yes you would put a one in them. Press submit and they all change back to zero to put the next ballot paper in. Then you press a calculate button to work out the totals.

Comment: I would suggest you have 5 text boxes and allow the user to enter the preferences exactly as they appear on the ballot paper. It would be a far neater and more efficient UI. Validation would be quite simple.

Comment: Ok i can change that. But how do I calculate the winner! How do I work out who has the highest number and if its a draw who has the most number of 1's ect.

Comment: I've got enough to do an answer, but I'm away a the moment so will have a go Sunday if that's OK.

Comment: That's fab thanks. Ill keep trying till then!!! I can work out totals just getting it to say who that total belongs to is the difficult bit.

Comment: Did you manage to have a look ENGIMATVITY?

Comment: There you go - I've put up my solution.

Comment: I'm getting on OK with it I am just keen to understand it rather then just copy and paste! I get everything up to the bit where you define the CandidateVotes in the DIsplayResult() sub. Are you able to just explain that bit to me. I have never used the function statement before or enumerable. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've put together an app that I think does what you need. It's fairly basic, so you would need to do more with it to make it really useful, but it works.

Here's the main UI showing four main states of the app while votes are being entered:

[image: Entering Votes]

So, in the first panel you see then app when it runs. It can be closed without entering any votes.

In the second panel you see a partially entered voting slip. Notice that the <kbd>Close</kbd> button is now called <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but is disabled because the user hasn't entered all of the votes correctly.

In the third panel the votes are entered correctly and now the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button is enabled and when it is clicked the current voting slip is stored.

The fourth panel shows the UI after a voting slip has been entered. You can continue to enter more slips or you can select <kbd>Done</kbd>. If you start entering more votes the app moves back to panel 2.

In this way you can enter as many voting slips as you need and it stores the validated votes in the following list of integer arrays:

```
Private _votes As List(Of Integer()) = New List(Of Integer())
```

When the user hits <kbd>Done</kbd> the app displays the winning candidate, or, in the case of an actual draw, shows the candidates that drew.

The calculation for this is as follows:

```
Dim candidateVotes = _
    Enumerable _
        .Range(0, 5) _
        .Select(Function(i) _
            _votes _
                .Select(Function(v) v(i)) _
                .OrderBy(Function (n) n) _
                .ToArray())

Dim candidates = _
    candidateVotes _
        .Select(Function(c, n) New With _
        { _
            .Candidate = n + 1, _
            .Summary = c.Sum().ToString("0000") & "," & String.Join(",", c) _
        }) _
        .OrderBy(Function(x) x.Summary) _
        .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Summary, Function(x) x.Candidate)
```

Now, if I started with the following sample data:

```
_votes.Add({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})
_votes.Add({5, 1, 2, 3, 4})
_votes.Add({3, 4, 5, 1, 2})
_votes.Add({3, 4, 2, 1, 5})
_votes.Add({1, 3, 2, 4, 5})
```

Then I would expect to see these results:

```
Candidate 1, Summary "0013,1,1,3,3,5" 
Candidate 4, Summary "0013,1,1,3,4,4" 
Candidate 2, Summary "0014,1,2,3,4,4" 
Candidate 3, Summary "0014,2,2,2,3,5" 
Candidate 5, Summary "0021,2,4,5,5,5"
```

Candidates 1 & 4 received the same number of total votes `13`, but because candidate 1 had more `3` preferences than candidate 4 then they won the election.

The key to this calculation is in making the `.Summary` string sortable so that once sorted the first summary string shows the winner (unless there are more than one candidate with the same summary string as the first one then it is a draw).

Here is the full code for my form:

```
Public Class EnterVotes

    Private _votes As List(Of Integer()) = New List(Of Integer())
    Private _textBoxes As TextBox() = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _textBoxes = {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
        ValidateVotes()
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged, TextBox3.TextChanged, TextBox4.TextChanged, TextBox5.TextChanged
        ValidateVotes()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Select Case Button1.Text
            Case "Close"
                Me.Close()
            Case "Enter"
                _votes.Add(_textBoxes.Select(Function(tb) Integer.Parse(tb.Text)).ToArray())
                For Each tb In _textBoxes
                    tb.Text = ""
                Next
                ValidateVotes()
            Case "Done"
                DisplayResult()
                Me.Close()
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Function GetTextBoxValue(tb As TextBox) As Integer?
        Dim value As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(tb.Text, value) Then
            Return value
        End If
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Private Sub ValidateVotes()
        If _textBoxes.All(Function(tb) tb.Text = "") Then
            If _votes.Any() Then
                Button1.Text = "Done"
            Else
                Button1.Text = "Close"
            End If
            Button1.Enabled = True
        Else
            Button1.Text = "Enter"
            If _textBoxes.Select(Function(tb) GetTextBoxValue(tb)).OrderBy(Function(n) n).SequenceEqual({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) Then
                Button1.Enabled = True
            Else
                Button1.Enabled = False
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayResult()
        Dim candidateVotes = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(Function(i) _votes.Select(Function(v) v(i)).ToArray())
        Dim candidates = candidateVotes.Select(Function(c, n) New With {.Candidate = n + 1, .Votes = c.Sum().ToString("0000") & "," & String.Join(",", c.OrderBy(Function(x) x))}).OrderBy(Function(x) x.Votes).GroupBy(Function(x) x.Votes, Function(x) x.Candidate)
        Dim firsts = candidates.First()
        If firsts.Count() > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("There was a draw with these candidates - " & String.Join(", ", firsts))
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Candidate {0} won.", firsts.First()))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: this looks amazing! thank you so much. I am going to try fitting this code in with mine and see if I do it all correctly!!! I shall let you know how I get on. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the principles of object oriented programming. Give each one its own object with properties.

```
Public Class Candidate

 private property v1 as integer
 private property v2 as integer
 private property v3 as integer
.
.
.
```

Each time they get a vote, then increase that property. For example, it they get a 1 vote, then add that to the property for v1.

```
Candidate.v1 += 1
```

Then you could simply add up all the property values to get a total of votes and if there is a tie, then go through each property and compare it since you will have a count of it.

```
If Candidate1.v1 > Candidate2.v1 then ...
```

That way you can see if candidate1 has more 1 votes then candidate 2